# Adding notification "Dot" in gnome

Tags: gnome3, notifications

Is there a way to add a dot to notifications from specific applications, similar to an update notification? I've switched today to Geary e-mail, and am missing a claws-mail feature that made notifications similar to these system notifications, dot wise speaking, whenever I got new mail.

I'm using Gnome 3, Debian.

To be clear, I'm talking of the dot appearing to the left of the time at the top bar. The current behavior of the mail client is to balloon the notification message, then hide it in the notification area, so I have to look for it if I missed the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this seems to be a "hard" problem. In any case, I found a workaround using the [Notifications Alert](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/258/notifications-alert-on-user-menu/) extension by hackedbellini.

You can color (and blink if you want) the date if there is an unread notification. It offers blacklisting or whitelisting if you want to filter which applications this works for.